# Why group_concat return too recording for the first row?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have an sql request and in this one I use function GROUP_CONCAT. I use this to have a list of delegue in each row.

This is my request:

```
SELECT pro.company, pro.title AS person_title, pro.name AS person_name, pro.firstname AS person_firstname, pro.address, pro.address2, pro.postcode, cities.name AS city, pro.phone, pro.gsm, pro.fax, pro.email, pro.client_number AS sap, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT user.firstname, ' ', user.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS delegue, agency.name AS agency, CONCAT(drv.firstname, ' ', drv.name) AS drv_name, drv.email AS drv_email, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pc.competence_id SEPARATOR ',') AS competences
    FROM velux.professionnal pro
    INNER JOIN velux.cities ON cities.id = pro.city_id
    INNER JOIN velux.zone ON pro.postcode BETWEEN zone.postcode_start AND postcode_end
    LEFT JOIN velux.p2p_user_zones user_zones ON user_zones.zone_id = zone.id
    LEFT JOIN velux.p2p_user user ON user.id = user_zones.user_id
    left join velux.p2p_user_group on p2p_user_group.user_id = user.id
    LEFT JOIN velux.agency ON zone.agency_id = agency.id
    LEFT JOIN velux.p2p_user drv ON drv.id = agency.user_id
    LEFT JOIN velux.professionnal_competence pc ON pc.professionnal_id = pro.id
    WHERE p2p_user_group.group_id in (10, 3)
    GROUP BY pc.professionnal_id
```

My problem is in the first row of my records the column delegue has too much result as expected :(. But for the other row it's ok. I don't know what is this bug and I don't know how to resolve it.

Someone have an idea ? If yes it would be great ! Thank in advance !

Comment: You have a lot of joins there it could be a data issue. I woudl try removing some of the joins (or start with just the first table) and slowly add the joins in to check to see where your duplicates start showing up.  Then if it is due to a specfic join, check the data in that table to see if it is a data issue.

Comment: The WHERE clause condition makes the p2p_user_group left join return inner join result. Move that condition to the ON clause to get true left join result.

Comment: What do you mean to move my where clause ? Because I need it to take the delegue in group_id 3 and 10.

Comment: @Arendelle this way (then remove your WHERE clause) :     left join velux.p2p_user_group on p2p_user_group.user_id = user.id AND p2p_user_group.group_id in (10, 3)

Comment: Your are using GROUP BY In a invalid way.. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/.. General rule about GROUP BY rule is the columns you select should also be in the GROUP BY... MySQL in lower versions have lesser strict rules about GROUP BY usage unless only_full_group_by as sql_mode is enabled.

Comment: @Aurelien I try your solution but unfortunately for each row there are too lot delegue I expected. It's like my first problem but now for all recoding.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't understand because I put the id who is the most important

Comment: @Arendelle it was not a solution to your problem, it was just a logic issue with your query

Comment: @Aurelien I see but I don't know How I can have the delegue I want with this logic.

Comment: @Aurelien Oh And I change the line finally I delete the "left" on left join like this (I keep your proposition):
`join velux.p2p_user_group on p2p_user_group.user_id = user.id AND (p2p_user_group.group_id =10 OR p2p_user_group.group_id =3)`
And I back to my first problem. I mean the first recording show me all delegue I expected and the rest is ok

Comment: Finally I found the solution! And you have right! I just change this line: 
`LEFT JOIN velux.professionnal_competence pc ON pc.professionnal_id = pro.id` in INNER JOIN and it's work :). Thank you for your help!